# How to get ui.Image(dart:ui) from network image?

Tags: flutter, android-canvas, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to write an image to canvas using Picture recorder...

drawImage requires dart:ui image

I have successfully imported asset image but getting following error for network image:

> [VERBOSE-2:codec.cc(97)] Failed decoding image. Data is either
>   invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
>
> [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception: Exception:
>   operation failed
>   0      _rootHandleUncaughtError. (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
>   1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
>   2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)

code tried so far..

```
netImage.obtainKey(new ImageConfiguration()).then((val) {
  var load = netImage.load(val);

  load.addListener((listener, err) async {
    ImageInfo imageInfo;
    setState(() => imageInfo = listener);

    imageInfo.image.toByteData().then((ss) {

      Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(ss.buffer);

      ui.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then((val) {
        val.getNextFrame().then((vaal) {
          imagetoDraw = vaal.image;
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23761

Answer (score 17):

I faced the same problem. I resolved it by the snippet code as below:

```dart
Future<Image> getImage(String path) async {
  final completer = Completer<ImageInfo>();
  final img = NetworkImage(path);
  img.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty).addListener(
    ImageStreamListener((info, _) {
      completer.complete(info);
    }),
  );
  final imageInfo = await completer.future;
  
  return imageInfo.image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23761

```
    netImage.obtainKey(new ImageConfiguration()).then((val) {
      var load = netImage.load(val);

      load.addListener((listener, err) async {

        setState(() => imageInfo = listener);

//        imageInfo.image.toByteData().then((ss) {
//
//          Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(ss.buffer);
//
////          ui.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then((val) {
////            val.getNextFrame().then((vaal) {
////              imagetoDraw = vaal.image;
////            });
////          });
//        });
      });
    });
```

and then..

```
c.drawImage(imageInfo.image, offset3, paint);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution but what ever I try I get `The argument type 'Future<Null> Function(dynamic, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'` error at `load.addListener`. Maybe you have any idea why it is happening?